# Rails Devise generate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-generate

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm trying to set up devise and omniauth to allow users to login to my website with the Facebook API. I'm using this tutorial http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2012/01/20/adding-facebook-auth-to-rails-3-1-app/ to do this. However, when I try to run  `rails generate devise User` , I get this error: `undefined local variable or method config for main:Object (NameError)`. How do I fix this?

devise.rb file :

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com" 
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

development.rb:

```
*******::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Comment: the correct command is `rails generate devise User` i am not sure if you are getting the error due to that but you can try

Comment: Sorry, edited my question - I was using the correct command.

Comment: please paste your devise.rb file it may be issue in that file as it is not able to find config there

Comment: which version of devise are you using?

Comment: your config variable is not in proper block in any of the config files which is giving this error. devise.rb looking fine try searching in development.rb it is in block `YourApplicationName::Application.configure do` block.

Comment: what do I need to search for?

Comment: in development.rb look for config variable if it is properly placed in block i have mentioned above. Or in some other config files if it is properly declared or used.

Comment: its also look fine sorry I had the same issue and it was in there only so I told you to check.

Comment: paste the whole error message it must be giving you some filename in error also is it?

Comment: does anybody happen to know what was causing this? I seem to be having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. abhas in the comments helped me get on the right track!

I had put `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in outside the `Module ApplicationName` block in the `config/Application.rb` folder. I put that config line in the Module block, and everything started working great!

```
module VitogoWeb2
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # A devise setting to prevent Heroku from accessing the DB or load models when precompiling the assets.
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  end
end
```